# How to get current time in ms in PHP?

Tags: php, time

What I want to get is the very like `time()`,but should be accurate in ms:

```
2010-11-15 21:21:00:987
```

Is that possible in PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function udate($format, $utimestamp = null) {
  if (is_null($utimestamp))
    $utimestamp = microtime(true);

  $timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
  $milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000000);

  return date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $milliseconds, $format), $timestamp);
}

echo udate('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'); // 2010-11-15 21:21:00:987
```

Comment: The `u` format character for `date()` already returns the microseconds since PHP 5.2.2. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Aether when I type `echo date('u');` I get `000000` in PHP 5.3  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, my mistake. The manual also states this: "Since this function only accepts integer timestamps the `u` format character is only useful when using the `date_format()` function with user based timestamps created with `date_create()`."

Answer (score 9):

Use [microtime](http://de.php.net/microtime) and convert it to milliseconds:

```
$millitime = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `microtime()` function.

See the manual page here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

[EDIT] To get the output in year/month/day/hour/minutes/seconds/ms as requested:

Try something like this:

```
list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
$output = date('Y/m/d H:i:s',$sec). " /" . $usec;
```

Again, see the manual page for more details on how `microtime()` works.

Comment: It returns µsecs, not msecs. Additionally it returns a 'msec sec' string if you don't pass true as the first argument.

Comment: The manual page gives examples on working with the return value; that's why I linked to it.

Comment: µsecs is fine,but I need to get the result in year/month/day/hour/minutes/seconds/ms ...

Answer (score 1):

This is my way

```
list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
$time =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s:",$sec).intval(round($usec*1000));
echo $time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 7.3 `hrtime` has been available.

This means you can use high resolution timers in nanoseconds without any of the issues of microtime.  (e.g. System clock changing between tests)

So, you can now get ms reliably on 64bit platforms with :

```
intval( hrtime(true) / 1000000 ); //Convert nanosecond to ms
```

Format as described in earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at php's [microtime function](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Comment: But how to get year/month/day/hour/minutes/seconds/ms out of it?