# How to get timestamp value in php which is similar to getTime() in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, timestamp

Following javascript code gives me output like : 1314066350368

```
new Date().getTime();
```

I would like to generate similar timestamp in PHP in order to get server's timestamp. 
kindly suggest me how to do it in PHP so my PHP code will generate exactly similar timestamps.

P.S. I do know about time() and microtime() functions in PHP. But i am looking forward to get similar outputs as i have mentioned above.

Comment: No search effort, see: http://www.google.com/search?q=timestamp+php

Comment: This question will show you how to do it using microtime() to get the time in milliseconds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184769/how-to-get-current-time-in-ms-in-php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo microtime(true)*1000;
?>
```

Comment: your code gives me output like : `1.31406855165E+12` . I am looking for a PHP method which gives output similar to `new Date().getTime();` code.

Comment: `<?php echo number_format(microtime(true)*1000,0,'.',''); ?>` this should work

Answer (score 0):

Did you try int time ( void ), Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Answer (score -1):

the following php results time stamp that is similar to javascript 'new Date().getTime()'

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Precision must be zero. Your code [returns false results](http://3v4l.org/XdFMe). See my answer for more details.