# PHP equivalent to a javascript timestamp (milliseconds not micro)

Tags: php, javascript, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get current time in ms in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184769/how-to-get-current-time-in-ms-in-php)

I am trying to figure out the best way to get the current time in milliseconds. As a company I am doing work for stores milliseconds in a database as they lay claim that its more accurate as far as UTC conversion goes. They obtain most of these times via javascripts date function. So what I am trying to figure is what is the best way to do this php side. I see mixed results.

`time()*1000` seems to be popular, but for me that doesnt make sense, as your ending up with a normal timestamp with 3 additional zeros at the end, which yea thats closer to accurate, but still not exact. I have also seen

`microtime(time(), TRUE)` or something to the extent there of, but that returns a result with a decimal from what I gather. Which again isn't up to par with what I am looking for. That said. Whats the best approach to getting a javascript readable version of a javascript style timestamp created by PHP on the fly?

Comment: Find solution on this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184769/how-to-get-current-time-in-ms-in-php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`microtime(time(), TRUE)` is not valid and `time()*1000` would not give you the best result

You can try

Javascript

```
 document.write(new Date().getTime()); // 1348773527231
```

PHP

```
print(round(microtime(true) * 1000)); // 1348773528231
```

Comment: I knew the microtime I used in my post was invalid, I couldnt remember the method I saw when I was prompted to write the question. And time x 1000 never sat well with me either. however. I didn't even think about rounding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

microtime(true) does not = time()*1000

```
// Start
$stamp = microtime(true);

// End
$total_time = microtime(true) - $stamp;

echo $total_time;
```

And if you don't want decimals use round($stamp);